# Is 'I would like to make laugh from you' correct?

Tags: phrasing, syntactic-analysis

With the meaning to make jokes about somebody. Or, 'They love to make laugh from me', is it correct? or should it be 'at' instead of 'from'?

Comment: Check the verb phrase "make fun of".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'I would like to make fun of you.'

'They love to make fun of me' or 'They love to make jokes at my expense.'

'Make laugh' isn't used much in the US, other than in constructs like 'You make me laugh.'
Put together as you did, the phrases have a bit of a Russian or Japanese flavor to them.
They're also ambiguous: 'make laugh from you' could mean either 'I want to make you laugh' or 'I want to make fun of you.'